# Assumptions needed for the matrix to be non-singular

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant, singularity

Given an $n$ by $n$ matrix A which is singular, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x_i <0 \quad \forall 1 \le i \le n$. I'm wondering under which assumptionw on $A$, the following matrix
$$
B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
    A &  x\\
    1_{1 \times n} & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
is non-singular. I'm stuck and find it rather tough when both of the matrices on the the diagonal of $B$ is singular, even though the structure of $B$ looks not too complicated.

Could anyone kindly suggest any ideas? I'd appreciate that a lot.

Comment: One simple observation: for brevity let $N_A$ be the null space of $A$, and $N_b$ be the null space of $1_{1 \times n}$. Note that $\dim(N_b) = n-1$. The inequality $$ \dim(N_A) + \dim(N_b) - \dim(N_A \cap N_b) = \dim(N_A + N_b) \leq n$$ then reduces to $$\dim(N_A) - 1 \leq \dim(N_A \cap N_b).$$ This implies that $\dim(N_A)$ cannot be larger than $1$...

Comment: For suppose it is. Then $\dim(N_A \cap N_b) > 0$, hence $N_A \cap N_b$ is nontrivial, so there is some nonzero vector $v$ in both null spaces. Then the vector $v' \in \mathbb R^{n+1}$, formed by appending a zero to $v$, is in the null space of $B$. Hence $B$ is singular.

Comment: Since $A$ is singular, the above implies that $\dim(N_A) = 1$. So $N_A$ is the set of all scalar multiples of some vector $v$. One additional constraint is that the sum of the elements of this vector $v$ cannot be zero. Otherwise, again, the vector $v'$ formed by appending a zero will be in the null space of $B$.